# Reading messages using JavaMail (POP3)

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, pop3

I'm trying to read messages with attachments from gmail using POP3 (I can't change it to IMAP). I have a problem because when I read attachment first time I'm unable to read this one again. It means that when I call method:

```
Message[] messages = inboxfolder.getMessages();
```

next time it returns only new messages. It is important to me, because when something goes wrong during first reading it is impossible to get some messages from server.

I've found that message is set as seen after:

```
Multipart multipart = (Multipart) messageWithAttach.getContent(); 
BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
```

Is it possible to often gets all messages, or messages I've marked as seen (I know that POP3 doesn't support flags from JavaMail)?